# Warning:"Dereferencing NULL pointer. 'Node.link' contains the same NULL value as 'next' did. See line 74 for an earlier location where this can occur"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, dereference

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class LinkedList {
// too lazy to make stuff private and write getters and setters.
public:
    struct Node {
        unsigned int ival = 0;
        struct Node* link = nullptr;
    };
    struct Node Node;
    LinkedList(unsigned int ival) {
        auto temp = new struct Node();
        temp->ival = ival;
        Node.ival++;
        Node.link = temp;
    }
    void addNode(unsigned int pos, int ival) {
        struct Node* newNode = new struct Node();
        newNode->ival = ival;
        switch (pos)
        {
        // create a new root node
        case 0:
            newNode->link = Node.link;
            Node.link = newNode;
            break;
        default:
            auto temp = Node.link;
            // go to the node before
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Node.ival - 1 && i < pos - 1; i++) {
                temp = temp->link;
            }
            // link the new Node 
            newNode->link = temp->link;
            // insert node
            temp->link = newNode;
        }
        // increment only at the end
        Node.ival++;
    }
    void deleteNode(unsigned int pos) {
        // decrement before to indicate the node will be deleted or the for loop won't work;
        Node.ival--;
        struct Node* leak = nullptr;
        switch (pos)
        {
        case 0:
            // store for deletion to prevent leak
            leak = Node.link;
            // correct the links to omit the node to be deleted
            Node.link = Node.link->link;
            break;
        default:
            auto temp = Node.link;
            // go to the node before
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Node.ival - 1 && i < pos - 1; i++) {
                temp = temp->link;
            }
            // store for deletion to prevent leak
            leak = temp->link;
            // correct the links to omit the node to be deleted
            temp->link = temp->link->link;
            break;
        }
        delete leak;
    }
    void reverse(unsigned int begin, unsigned int end) {

    }
    void reverse() {
        // root node stored in prev
        auto prev = Node.link;
        // root->next in next
        auto next = prev->link;
        while (next != nullptr) {
            auto temp_store = next->link;
            next->link = prev;
            prev = next;
            next = temp_store;
        }
        Node.link->link = nullptr;
        Node.link = prev;
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList linkedList(10);
    linkedList.addNode(3, 20);
    linkedList.addNode(1, 15);
    linkedList.addNode(0, 5);
    linkedList.addNode(-1, 25);
    linkedList.addNode(-1, 30);
    linkedList.reverse();
    return 0;
}
```

All the functions have been tested. Warning is received at line 81, namely `Node.link->link = nullptr;`. What have I missed?

---

EDIT:
It seems `Node` is misleading. The structure of the list is supposed to be on the following lines:

```
Node->node0->node1->node2->....
```

Node although in itself a full-fledged object is used to store count of nodes and link to the root node.

Comment: How do you know that Node.link isnt null? if it is the Node.link->link is a null deref. (in both cases)

Comment: You missed to use a debugger to inspect `Node.link` values and fix that case where it isn't initialized,

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him technically what happens if you create a LinkedList and delete the only node in it? I tried it and I get a segfault.

Comment: you see, `leak` will point to `nullptr` in your case, trying to call `delete` on which, gives you the `SIGSEGV`

Comment: I think the mixed use of `ival` and `pos` in `addnode` is a mess.

Comment: but the warning is in the `reverse` function, no?

Comment: The point is not where the warning arises, but where it comes from. I'd std:cout the whole lined list just at the beggining of `reverse()`

Comment: Also worth addressing some of these when you get a chance: https://godbolt.org/z/fKT48Es4W

Comment: @user4581301, Ah! Memory leak, my old foe...

Comment: @user4581301, I still don't understand what is causing the leak. Help me a little please?

Comment: This sequence crashes: `LinkedList linkedList(10); linkedList.deleteNode(0); linkedList.reverse();` The warning tells you that `Node.link->link = nullptr;` may, under some circumstances, dereference a null pointer. And indeed it may - when `reverse()` is called on an empty list.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks. Um, can you also please explain why the Godbolt is showing memory leak?

Comment: Because you don't deallocate any of the nodes in the list when the list is destroyed. There are plenty of places that use `new`, but the only use of `delete` is in `deleteNode`, which the example never calls.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, do you mean, no dtor?